# Karma+Mocha+Browserify+ES6 testing stack setup problems

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, mocha.js, karma-runner, babeljs

I am trying to create a testable front-end project along these guidelines:

- React component architecture with `__test__` folders in each component folder;
- tests use ES6 modules;
- browserify bundles everything into one file while babelify transpiles ES6;
- karma uses the bundle for testing.

This is my `karma.conf.js`:

```
module.exports = function (karma) {
    const testFiles = __dirname + '/proj/static/src/**/__tests__/*.js';

    karma.set({
        frameworks: ['browserify', 'mocha'],
        browsers: ['Chrome'],
        files: [
            testFiles
        ],
        logLevel: 'LOG_DEBUG',
        preprocessors: {
            testFiles: ['browserify'],
        },
        reporters: ['dots'],
        singleRun: true,

        browserify: {
            debug: true,
            transform: [ 'babelify' ]
        },
    });
};
```

This is my `.babelrc`

```
{
  presets: ['es2015', 'react']
}
```

However, after launching karma, I get this error:

```
...
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
  at proj/static/src/js/some-component/__tests__/some.test.js:1
```

Clearly the code doesn't get transpiled. I've read multiple tutorials, and all use different technologies. Any ideas how to fix the problem?

P.S. I am still very fresh with TDD in the front-end.

**Edit**
These are the installed npm dependencies:

```
"babel-preset-es2015": "^6.18.0",
"babel-preset-react": "^6.16.0",
"babelify": "^7.3.0",
"browserify": "^13.1.1",
"expect": "^1.20.2",
"karma": "^1.3.0",
"karma-browserify": "^5.1.0",
"karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
"karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
"karma-mocha": "^1.3.0",
"mocha": "^3.1.2",
"reactify": "^1.1.1",
"watchify": "^3.7.0"
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `testFiles` is the value of the key in the `preprocessors` configuration. You need the value of the key to be a glob that matches the files that are to be preprocessed. No files are being matched, so no files are being preprocessed.

I would try this:

```
preprocessors: {
    '**/*.js': ['browserify']
}
```

Your question doesn't go into detail about your project's directory structure, so I've suggested a glob that matches all `.js` files. You could refine it to match only your source files that need to be transpiled.

Be aware that the glob will need to match all of your source files - not just the tests.

Comment: The change in configuration seems to solve this problem. But now after `./node_modules/.bin/karma start`, I get a barrage of errors from browserify that look like this `[framework.browserify]: bundle error: Cannot find module './runnable' from 'D:\proj\node_modules\mocha'`.
Yet Mocha is installed locally. And modules at given paths exist.